# How can I keep only 100 latest entries in CSV file per group

Tags: javascript, python, csv

I have an application where I need to measure timestamp based parameter values from each device. The information is heavily structured and the reason I haven't looked into databases is because I have to get all the data for 100 x 1000 = 100k rows every few minutes. I want to delete the data corresponding to the oldest timestamp in each group. I am using Python for programming but even JavaScript would do. I could not find the limit parameter in the Python CSV official module. Help is super appreciated.

```
Item 1
Timestamp, parameter1, parameter2...parameterN
...
100 rows
Item 2
Timestamp, parameter1, parameter2...parameterN
...
100 rows
...1000 items
```

**Note:** There are no headers to separate any rows, the Item 1,2 etc. are shown for representational purposes.

I need to be able to add new row every few minutes under each group and get rid of the old one effectively keeping the numbers at 100 per group

Comment: so you have a header every hundred rows?

Comment: no headers in any rows, just for representational purposes

Comment: @SethMcClaine you mean we store the file in the reverse and limit by max size? Yup doesnt matter how we read it I guess

Comment: in javascript, you'd convert the csv to an array order by timestamp, and then keep just `array.slice(-100)` - hope that helps

Comment: thanks @SethMcClaine man I did not even consider this possibility lol, I thought I could delete specific line numbers and do a regex to remove blank lines like a human truncating the file but this helps man! I will try this, open() in python loads the entire file into memory I guess

Comment: Welcome @PirateApp

Comment: You can convert to a list and then slice that list, just like in JS, but if we're talking about a huge file, that means building a huge list just to throw most of it away, and avoiding that is a lot easier in Python than in JS.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `limit` parameter, because a reader is just an iterator, and Python has generic ways to do anything you might want to do with any iterator.

```
with open(path) as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
```

First 100:

```
itertools.islice(r, 100)
```

Last 100:

```
collections.deque(r, maxlen=100)
```

Max 100 by 3rd column:

```
heapq.nlargest(100, r, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

… and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Store your data internally like this

dict [key] [timestamp][array of values]

```
data={}

if 'bob' in data:
    data['bob']={}
    data['bob'][timestamp]=list(values)
else:
    data['bob'][new_timestamp]=list(values)
```

After 2 iterations your data array will look like

```
data['bob'][15000021][1,2,3,4,5]
data['bob'][15003621][5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

If you want the latest ... just get the unique keys for bob - and delete

```
- either anything more than n items (bob's values sorted by timestamp)
- or if the timestamp is less than now() - 2 days [or whatever your rule]
```

I use both mechanisms in similar datasets. I strongly suggest you then save this data, in case your process exists.

Should your data contain an OrderedDictionary (which would make the removal easier) - please not pickle will fail, however the excellent module **dill** (I am not kidding) is excellent, and handles all datatypes and closes much nicer IMHO.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about Hbase, as this is essentially what HBase does with it's data records. You would need to slightly change the key from being  'Bob' to 'Bob15000021' - and then retrieve the data using a Scan. Super fast - and super flexible (Infinite number of columns/ data points).

Comment: thanks for the pointer! @Tim Seed I will definitely have a look into this

Comment: I was watching this vid on HBase introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ci_QxJ1kiE and the guy mentions that if you want to read a few random rows from a petabyte of data, hbase is a good use case but for reading everything it isnt, i will dive into this a bit but in my case i have to read all the 100k items every few mins

Comment: Ouch ... reading 100K rows ... err No that does not sound to be a good use of HBase. Storing 10 Billion rows - easy. As long as each row is less than 2Gb of data. Then you need to look into sharding your data sets. If you are talking of mass processing in Hadoop then Spark - but HDFS is typically Read-Only ... so not the best solution for you. DB Time ... 100k Rows easy.

Answer (score 1):

** Moving from Comments **

I'm assuming reading the file from the bottom up help you... This can be done by prepending entries to the beginning of the file.

With that assumption you just need to rewrite the file on each entry. Read the new file to an array, `push()` the new entry, `shift()` the list and write to new file.

Alternatively you can continue to `push()` to the file and only read the first 100 entries. After doing your read you can remove the file and start a new one if you expect to consistently get more than 100 entries between reads, or you can clean the file to just 100 entries

Comment: thanks for the answer, testing the solutions one by one :)